# Is there a way for me to get Mathematica show its steps?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic, summation

I have seen similar questions but they were quite dated (3+ years). When performing, say an Integration, it would be beneficial to see the major steps such as variable substitution, change the order of integration, perform by-parts, etc.
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what about [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148/7167) is dated and unsatisfactory to you?

Comment: This was asked two months ago in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76225; also http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6811, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2239; several marked as a duplicates of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/148

Comment: `Integrate` in general does not do things in a way that would be recognizable from basic calculus.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I was wondering if newer versions of Mathematica has newer features on the subject.

Comment: …at least, not unless they've started teaching Risch to kids these days.

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: The Risch algorithm is the core method used for symbolic integration in most software. Searching for it in your favorite search engine should turn up at least a useful introduction.

Comment: Thanks, now I got it. I googled the name before and all I saw was a politician!